# Does wikipedia block jquery-loading of their images

Tags: javascript, wikipedia

If I attempt to dynamically set an html image source to a wikipedia image, it fails, but other images work.

```
// does NOT work
jQuery( "#my_img" )
  .attr( "src" , 
         "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Grad_Zovnek_Vischer.jpg" )

// works
jQuery( "#my_img" )
  .attr( "src" , 
         "http://dgroover.wikispaces.com/file/view/bill-gates-car.jpg" )
```

Does wikipedia somehow block loading of their images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Grad_Zovnek_Vischer.jpg`. You're not using the direct link.

Comment: where did you get this from please: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/" ... ... is that a standard directory for all images?

Comment: Right click the image in your link and click 'copy url'. Or 'open image in new tab'.

Comment: hmmm ... of course ... I suppose another question could be: **what is the best practice for extracting the primary image from a wikipedia article** ... but I bet the wikipedia API handles that somehow :) thanks.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Have a look at [`prop=pageimages`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query+pageimages) in MediaWiki API.